# xamarin.forms using lass library on server as well as in Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, server, shared-libraries

I am developping a Xamarin.Forms (C#) app that calls HTML pages / Webservice Methods from an ASP.Net server.

Both app and server are sharing some classes that reside in a separate DLL. To avoid unnessesary memory usage in the app: will the whole class library be added to the app's APK or are will only the classes definitely used be linked?

With other words: Should I create a separate shared library with just the classes used by both app and server?